# Trim Line After Third Occurence of Colon

Tags: bash, sed

I am parsing through a log file and I am trying to clean up the output.

Here's a sample input line

```
2016-04-11 12:45:26 : TEXT TO REMOVE
```

Here's my current code which removes everything after the first colon.

```
sed 's/:.*//'
```

which outputs

```
2016-04-11 12
```

I'd like to modify this so that it removes everything after the third colon instead (so I end up with just the date and time).

Here's a sample output I would like:

```
2016-04-11 12:45:26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looking for the spaces surrounding the colon?

```
sed 's/ : .*//'
awk -F ' : ' '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 3):

That's what `cut` was invented to do:

```
$ cut -d':' -f1-3 file
2016-04-11 12:45:26
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sed:

```
str='2016-04-11 12:45:26 : TEXT TO REMOVE'
sed 's/ *:[^:]*$//' <<< "$str"
```

i.e. use `[^:]*$` pattern to make sure we match last segment of line after last `:`

**Output:**

```
2016-04-11 12:45:26
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking removing everything after the 3rd `:` is equivalent to print only the chars that are before it. `sed` would be easier to use that way.

Give this a try:

```
sed "s/^\([^:][^:]*:[^:][^:]*:[^:][^:]*\):.*$/\1/"
```

The same principle can be used to print only date time before `:`:

```
sed "s/^\([0-9][0-9]*-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*$/\1/g"
```

The chars in between the **\(** and the **\)** can be reused in the replacement section with **\1**.